# WatiN.Core.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible not working

Tags: c#, windows-7-x64, watin, internet-explorer-11

For some reason `WatiN.Core.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;` does not hide new Internet Explorer windows created in a new process like this:

```
WatiN.Core.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false
var ie = new WatiN.Core.IE(true);
```

I also tried `ie.ShowWindow(WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Hide);` but isn't capable of hiding the the window either.

Does anyone knows a workaround?

I'm running Windows 7 Pro x64 with Internet Explorer 11 with WatiN 2.1.0.1196

Thank you.

**Answer:**

After trying hiding the IE window with [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), after attempting to start IE with `Process.Start()` and specifying that I wish the window to be hidden. It turns out that simply changing: `var ie = new WatiN.Core.IE(true);` to `var ie = new WatiN.Core.IE(false);` worked in conjunction with `WatiN.Core.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false` (in my case at least).

The difference between them is that one the first snippet we start IE in a new process, on the other one we do not. I'm not really sure why this affects WatiN functionality so much on this matter though, if someone could provide some insight I would appreciate it.